# cleaning up a very messy text file with python

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have a messy text file, containing metadata for a database with hundreds of tables, i'm trying to get it to pandas so i have a nice CSV but this one is difficult, and I might be missing something earlier on that's causing problems

myfile.txt =

```
Table: "DBO"."PSDSTTIME"
Column list, count 8:
v_FileID r_FileID ColumnID DomainID Name         Type     Precision Scale MaxLength Nullability Nulls Min                         Max                         #Distinct 
-------- -------- -------- -------- ------------ -------- --------- ----- --------- ----------- ----- --------------------------- --------------------------- --------- 
    1058     1058        0        1 DSTID        CHAR     24              12        Y           N     0LastSunMar                 4LastSunOct                 21        
    1058     1058        1        2 DSTABSOLUTE  CHAR     2               1         Y           N     N                           N                           1         
    1058     1058        2        3 DSTMONTH     CHAR     4               2         Y           N     10                          9                           8         
    1058     1058        3        4 DSTDAY       SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     1                           5                           5         
    1058     1058        4        5 DSTDAYOFWEEK CHAR     2               1         Y           N     0                           5                           4         
    1058     1058        5        6 DSTHOUR      SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     0                           4                           5         
    1058     1058        6        7 DSTMINUTE    SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     0                           0                           1         
    1058     1058        7        8 DESCR        CHAR     60              30        Y           N     First Friday in May, 2:00am Third Sunday in Oct, 2:00am 21        

Ready>Check Files...OK
Load Data...OK
Table: "DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR"
Column list, count 29:
v_FileID r_FileID ColumnID DomainID Name              Type      Precision Scale MaxLength Nullability Nulls Min                              Max                              #Distinct 
-------- -------- -------- -------- ----------------- --------- --------- ----- --------- ----------- ----- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- --------- 
    1048     1048        0        1 RECURTYPE         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     2                                2                                1         
    1048     1048        1        2 RECURNAME         CHAR      60              30        Y           N     Daily Purge                      Y_DAILY3_NT2                     12        
    1048     1048        2        3 VERSION           INTEGER                   2         Y           N     1                                4                                3         
    1048     1048        3        4 DAYOFMONTH        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                0                                1         
    1048     1048        4        5 RUN1STWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     1                                1                                1         
    1048     1048        5        6 RUN2NDWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     2                                2                                1         
    1048     1048        6        7 RUN3RDWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     3                                3                                1         
    1048     1048        7        8 RUN4THWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     4                                4                                1         
    1048     1048        8        9 RUN5THWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     5                                5                                1         
    1048     1048        9       10 RUN6THWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     6                                6                                1         
    1048     1048       10       11 RUNSUNDAY         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                1                                2         
    1048     1048       11       12 RUNMONDAY         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     2                                2                                1         
    1048     1048       12       13 RUNTUESDAY        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     3                                3                                1         
    1048     1048       13       14 RUNWEDNESDAY      SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     4                                4                                1         
    1048     1048       14       15 RUNTHURSDAY       SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     5                                5                                1         
    1048     1048       15       16 RUNFRIDAY         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     6                                6                                1         
    1048     1048       16       17 RUNSATURDAY       SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                7                                2         
    1048     1048       17       18 RECURDAYSPCL      SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                0                                1         
    1048     1048       18       19 BEGINDTTM         TIMESTAMP                 32        Y           N     1999-01-01-17.00.00.000000000000 2014-08-23-10.59.24.000000000000 12        
    1048     1048       19       20 REPEATRECURRENCE  SMALLINT                  3         Y           N     0                                60                               8         
    1048     1048       20       21 REPEATUNIT        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                2                                3         
    1048     1048       21       22 DURATION          SMALLINT                  3         Y           N     0                                24                               4         
    1048     1048       22       23 DURATIONUNIT      SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                1                                2         
    1048     1048       23       24 INITIATEWHEN      SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                1                                2         
    1048     1048       24       25 RECURDESCR        CHAR      60              30        Y           N     Daily Purge                      Y_DAILY3_NT2 3Times              12        
    1048     1048       25       26 LASTUPDDTTM       TIMESTAMP                 32        Y           N     2001-08-14-16.25.54.000000000000 2014-08-23-10.59.38.000000000000 11        
    1048     1048       26       27 LASTUPDOPRID      CHAR      60              30        Y           N     CruiseC                          dcg01                            4         
    1048     1048       27       28 ENDDTTM           TIMESTAMP                 32        Y           Y     2005-02-01-00.00.00.000000000000 2005-02-01-00.00.00.000000000000 1         
    1048     1048       28       29 RECUR_USECURRDATE SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                1                                2         

Ready>Check Files...OK
```

so here's what I've tried to get close

```py
import re
with open('lmprod_metadata.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

pattern1 = re.compile('^\s*\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+.*$')
pattern2 = re.compile('^Table:.*$')

lines = [line for line in lines if pattern1.match(line) or pattern2.match(line)]

lines2 = [line.strip() for line in lines]

lines3 = [line for line in lines2]

# my thought for the following was to get table name in the rows to help standardize the data
table_names = []
data_columns = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i].startswith('Table'):
        table_name = lst[i].split()[1]
    else:
        data_columns.append(table_name + ' ' + lst[i])
```

here is the output for the first two tables shown in the example text file

```
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        0        1 DSTID        CHAR     24              12        Y           N     0LastSunMar                 4LastSunOct                 21
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        1        2 DSTABSOLUTE  CHAR     2               1         Y           N     N                           N                           1
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        2        3 DSTMONTH     CHAR     4               2         Y           N     10                          9                           8
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        3        4 DSTDAY       SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     1                           5                           5
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        4        5 DSTDAYOFWEEK CHAR     2               1         Y           N     0                           5                           4
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        5        6 DSTHOUR      SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     0                           4                           5
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        6        7 DSTMINUTE    SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     0                           0                           1
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        7        8 DESCR        CHAR     60              30        Y           N     First Friday in May, 2:00am Third Sunday in Oct, 2:00am 21
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        0        1 RECURTYPE         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     2                                2                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        1        2 RECURNAME         CHAR      60              30        Y           N     Daily Purge                      Y_DAILY3_NT2                     12
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        2        3 VERSION           INTEGER                   2         Y           N     1                                4                                3
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        3        4 DAYOFMONTH        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                0                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        4        5 RUN1STWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     1                                1                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        5        6 RUN2NDWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     2                                2                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        6        7 RUN3RDWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     3                                3                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        7        8 RUN4THWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     4                                4                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        8        9 RUN5THWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     5                                5                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        9       10 RUN6THWEEK        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     6                                6                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       10       11 RUNSUNDAY         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                1                                2
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       11       12 RUNMONDAY         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     2                                2                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       12       13 RUNTUESDAY        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     3                                3                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       13       14 RUNWEDNESDAY      SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     4                                4                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       14       15 RUNTHURSDAY       SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     5                                5                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       15       16 RUNFRIDAY         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     6                                6                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       16       17 RUNSATURDAY       SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                7                                2
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       17       18 RECURDAYSPCL      SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                0                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       18       19 BEGINDTTM         TIMESTAMP                 32        Y           N     1999-01-01-17.00.00.000000000000 2014-08-23-10.59.24.000000000000 12
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       19       20 REPEATRECURRENCE  SMALLINT                  3         Y           N     0                                60                               8
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       20       21 REPEATUNIT        SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                2                                3
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       21       22 DURATION          SMALLINT                  3         Y           N     0                                24                               4
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       22       23 DURATIONUNIT      SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                1                                2
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       23       24 INITIATEWHEN      SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                1                                2
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       24       25 RECURDESCR        CHAR      60              30        Y           N     Daily Purge                      Y_DAILY3_NT2 3Times              12
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       25       26 LASTUPDDTTM       TIMESTAMP                 32        Y           N     2001-08-14-16.25.54.000000000000 2014-08-23-10.59.38.000000000000 11
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       26       27 LASTUPDOPRID      CHAR      60              30        Y           N     CruiseC                          dcg01                            4
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       27       28 ENDDTTM           TIMESTAMP                 32        Y           Y     2005-02-01-00.00.00.000000000000 2005-02-01-00.00.00.000000000000 1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048       28       29 RECUR_USECURRDATE SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     0                                1                                2
```

so my issue is the way i've cleaned it to this point doesn't handle the arbitrary number of spaces well, i've tried OpenRefine, cleaninng the list further, and different separators in pandas with no success, i don't want to lose any data

here is trying to clean the data further using the data_columns table from the last example, so it is all space separated

```py
lst = []

for item in data_columns:
    clean_item = item.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\t', ' ')
    lst.append(clean_item)
```

output (including less because I'm running out of characters)

```
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        0        1 DSTID        CHAR     24              12        Y           N     0LastSunMar                 4LastSunOct                 21
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        1        2 DSTABSOLUTE  CHAR     2               1         Y           N     N                           N                           1
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        2        3 DSTMONTH     CHAR     4               2         Y           N     10                          9                           8
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        3        4 DSTDAY       SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     1                           5                           5
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        4        5 DSTDAYOFWEEK CHAR     2               1         Y           N     0                           5                           4
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        5        6 DSTHOUR      SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     0                           4                           5
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        6        7 DSTMINUTE    SMALLINT                 2         Y           N     0                           0                           1
"DBO"."PSDSTTIME" 1058     1058        7        8 DESCR        CHAR     60              30        Y           N     First Friday in May, 2:00am Third Sunday in Oct, 2:00am 21
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        0        1 RECURTYPE         SMALLINT                  2         Y           N     2                                2                                1
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        1        2 RECURNAME         CHAR      60              30        Y           N     Daily Purge                      Y_DAILY3_NT2                     12
"DBO"."PS_PRCSRECUR" 1048     1048        2        3 VERSION           INTEGER                   2         Y           N     1                                4                                3
```

here are the attempts with pandas

```py
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', delimiter='\s+')
# and
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep='\s+')
```

results in this error:

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', delimiter='\s+')

not including full output, running out of characters

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 15 fields in line 9, saw 22
```

i've already deleted some of the other text cleaning code I tried...which wasn't the best move but oh well, i think there has to be something upstream i can do, i'm just not sure?

Answer (score 2):

Seems a good *usecase* for [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) :

```
import re
from io import StringIO

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    splits = re.findall(r"Table:\s*(.*?)\n.*?\n(.*?)\n(?=Ready|$)", content, flags=re.DOTALL)
  
dfs = {table[0].replace('"', ""): pd.read_fwf(StringIO(table[1])).loc[1:] for table in splits}
​​
df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(level=0, names="table_name")
```

Output :

To access each table separately, use dict *key-indexing* :

```
print(dfs["DBO.PSDSTTIME"])
​
   v_FileID r_FileID ColumnID  ...                          Min                          Max #Distinct
1      1058     1058        0  ...                  0LastSunMar                  4LastSunOct        21
2      1058     1058        1  ...                            N                            N         1
3      1058     1058        2  ...                           10                            9         8
..      ...      ...      ...  ...                          ...                          ...       ...
6      1058     1058        5  ...                            0                            4         5
7      1058     1058        6  ...                            0                            0         1
8      1058     1058        7  ...  First Friday in May, 2:00am  Third Sunday in Oct, 2:00am        21

[8 rows x 14 columns]

print(dfs["DBO.PS_PRCSRECUR"])

   v_FileID r_FileID ColumnID  ...                               Min                               Max #Distinct
1      1048     1048        0  ...                                 2                                 2         1
2      1048     1048        1  ...                       Daily Purge                      Y_DAILY3_NT2        12
3      1048     1048        2  ...                                 1                                 4         3
..      ...      ...      ...  ...                               ...                               ...       ...
27     1048     1048       26  ...                           CruiseC                             dcg01         4
28     1048     1048       27  ...  2005-02-01-00.00.00.000000000000  2005-02-01-00.00.00.000000000000         1
29     1048     10
48       28  ...                                 0                                 1         2

[29 rows x 14 columns]
```

With [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), you get all the tables in the same *DataFrame* :

```
print(df)

          table_name v_FileID r_FileID  ...                               Min                               Max #Distinct
1      DBO.PSDSTTIME     1058     1058  ...                       0LastSunMar                       4LastSunOct        21
2      DBO.PSDSTTIME     1058     1058  ...                                 N                                 N         1
3      DBO.PSDSTTIME     1058     1058  ...                                10                                 9         8
..               ...      ...      ...  ...                               ...                               ...       ...
27  DBO.PS_PRCSRECUR     1048     1048  ...                           CruiseC                             dcg01         4
28  DBO.PS_PRCSRECUR     1048     1048  ...  2005-02-01-00.00.00.000000000000  2005-02-01-00.00.00.000000000000         1
29  DBO.PS_PRCSRECUR     1048     1048  ...                                 0                                 1         2

[37 rows x 15 columns]
```